# How to create new empty collection from existing one in same database?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I need to create new collection based on existing one(with same structure and columns) but dont need to copy any records. Important is to have same structure in new empty collection.

Comment: Mongodb is a document-oriented database, there are no columns and free structure for any document in a collection. Structure is dictated only by application and validation rules.

Comment: You may want to know if the copied collection needs to have the same indexes.

Answer (score 0):

> Important is to have same structure in new empty collection

if you want to ensure that documents structure in 2 different collections is the same, you can apply a $jsonSchema validation to each collections, see [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/jsonSchema/).